# form not matching list

Tags: list-form

I have rearranged the column order in my list, but my form is not matching the list order.   Why is this, and why am I prevented from simply deleting fields I do not need?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have content types enabled.  The form order will be based on the column order in the content type.  You can also mark particular columns as hidden in the content type to hide them from the form.